# Partitioning dataset in chunks and compute the means of these chunks automatically

Tags: python, data-science

I need to generate small chunks from a dataset. Then compute the mean of each chunk. Finally, create a list or array to store all these means. My goal is to automate the process.
For example:
my data is [2,5,1,5,3,8,4,2,33,65,34,11,42]. If chunk size is 3, then I expect to have:

```
part0 = mydata[0 : 3]  => 2, 5, 1      => mean0 = 2.66
part1 = mydata[3 : 6]  => 5, 3, 8      => mean1 = 5.33
part2 = mydata[6 : 9]  => 4, 2, 33     => mean2 = 13.0
part3 = mydata[9 : 12] => 65, 34, 11   => mean3 = 36.66
part4 = mydata[12 : ]  => 42           => mean4 = 42.0

list_of_means = {mean0, mean1, mean2, mean3, mean4}
```

I just couldn't figure out how to create the list of means.

Below is the code I tried using a For Loop and eval().

```
import numpy as np
mydata = [2,5,1,5,3,8,4,2,33,65,34,11,42]
chunk_size = 3
index_ref = [n for n in range(len(mydata*1000))]

for i in range(0, len(mydata)):

    globals()[f"part{i}"] ='mydata['+str(index_ref[i*chunk_size])+' : '+str(index_ref[(i*chunk_size)+chunk_size])+']' #This works
    
    globals()[f"mean{i}"] = eval(np.mean(eval('part'+str(i)))) #This brings an error
```

Comment: where does the program start? with the block with the import or in the block above? Don't get why you make use of globals and eval. Is it a mandatory condition?

Comment: try eval('np.mean(part+str({i}))')  with an eval less... I haven't tried but good luck

Comment: like this could gain some  performance ```range(len(mydata)*1000)```

Comment: Hi @cards, thanks for having a look. If I do this eval('np.mean(part+str({i}))'), it brings an error saying 'part' is not defined.

Comment: sitll have a problem?

Comment: this range(len(mydata)*1000) was just a get rid of an error. I was getting an 'out of range' issue if I only use range(len(mydata))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range()` can take `start`, `end`, and `step` arguments. So one of the canonical ways to get slices is to do something like this:

```py
# verbose
chunks = []

for i in range(0, len(mydata), chunk_size):
    chunks.append(mydata[i:i+chunk_size])

# or as comprehension
chunks = [mydata[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(mydata), chunk_size)]
```

Then compute the mean for each element, e.g.,

```py
from statistics import mean

list_of_means = [mean(c) for c in chunks]
```

**A general note:** Messing with `globals` and `eval` to instantiate variables is not only very verbose and unfeasible for larger datasets, it's also quite hacky, dangerous (because `eval` can execute arbitrary, potentially harmful code), and just not the preferred way of dealing with things. If you have a bunch of values, use an appropriate data structure like a list, a dict, or whatever fits the situation and process the items with `for`-loops. If you get an index error, try to understand what is causing it instead of using an ad-hoc patch that doesn't resolve the cause of the problem. That's just something to keep in mind for the future – we're all learning here, keep it up!

Comment: Hi @fsimonjetz, you are amazing. Thanks so much. This solution provides everything I needed. I'm voting for it. Your general note is true. I just experienced that I had to be careful with globals and eval. Anyway, I'm going to post a working code based on my initial approach just for future reference. There are some good techniques one my use for another application. Many many thanks for helping. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

try this...and tell me if it corresponds to what you need

```
# external paramters
data = [2,5,1,5,3,8,4,2,33,65,34,11,42]
chunk_size = 3

# program - chunker
remainder = len(data) % chunk_size
chunk_amounts = len(data) // chunk_size

if remainder != 0:
    chunk_amounts = len(data)//chunk_size + 1

chunks = []
for i in range(chunk_amounts):
    chunk = data[chunk_size * i: chunk_size * (i + 1)]
    mean = sum(chunk)//len(data) # as float, use // for an integer value
    chunks += [mean]

    print(i, chunk, mean)
```

**EDIT**  With `exec`

```
for i in range(0, len(mydata)):

    data_slice = 'mydata[' + str(index_ref[i * chunk_size]) + ' : ' + str(
        index_ref[(i * chunk_size) + chunk_size]) + ']'

    exec(f"part{i} = {data_slice}")
    exec(f'mean{i} = sum(part{i})//3')

print(part2)
print(mean2)
```

Output

```
[4, 2, 33]
13
```

**EDIT** with `eval`

```
mydata = [2, 5, 1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 33, 65, 34, 11, 42]
chunk_size = 3
index_ref = [n for n in range(len(mydata*5))]

for i in range(0, len(mydata)):

    data_slice_pattern = 'mydata[' + str(index_ref[i * chunk_size]) + ' : ' + str(
        index_ref[(i * chunk_size) + chunk_size]) + ']'

    globals()[f"part{i}"] = data_slice_pattern
    data_slice = eval(data_slice_pattern)
    globals()[f'mean{i}'] = sum(data_slice)//3

means = [m for m in globals() if 'mean' in m]

print('part2' in globals())
print(eval('part2'))
print('mean2' in globals())
print(eval('mean3'))
print(means)
```

Output

```
True
mydata[6 : 9]
True
36
['mean0', 'mean1', 'mean2', 'mean3', 'mean4', 'mean5', 'mean6', 'mean7', 'mean8', 'mean9', 'mean10', 'mean11', 'mean12']
```

Comment: I havn't installed ```numpy``` so I use standard library stuffs for the mean. @Dom Give me please a feedback on the "solutions" so in case I can correct them, thanks

Comment: Hi @cards, thanks for helping, I learnt good things from your code. I didn't call the means using this method:  means = [m for m in globals() if 'mean' in m]. It's bringing any global variable which contains "mean". i.e: if I had something like "var_mean", it will also appear... So I adjusted the code to get it to work as wanted. However, I'm convinced that my initial approach was not the best way to solve the question even though it's working. I'm going to post this solution just to show.

Comment: Good to hear that! Yes, there was a lot of uncertainty in your code... and since I didnt know exactly what you wanted I came out with the laziest solution ```means = [m for m in globals() if 'mean' in m].``` I personally prefer to stay away from ```globals``` but I took it as a design restricion:)

Answer (score 0):

A rather long working solution:

```
mydata = [2,5,1,5,3,8,4,2,33,65,34,11,42,76,12,76,31]

# program - chunker
chunk_size = 3 
remainder = len(mydata) % chunk_size 
chunk_amounts = len(mydata) // chunk_size
if remainder != 0:
    chunk_amounts = len(mydata)//chunk_size + 1
    
# prepare indexing
index_ref = [n for n in range(len(mydata*chunk_amounts))] #to avoid index out of range

# partitioning and mean calculation
for i in range(0, len(mydata)):

    globals()[f"part{i}"] ='mydata['+str(index_ref[i*chunk_size])+' : '+str(index_ref[(i*chunk_size)+chunk_size])+']'
      
    globals()[f"mean{i}"] = np.mean(eval(eval('part'+str(i))))

# build mean list
mean_list = []
for i in range(0, chunk_amounts):
    mean_list.append('mean'+str(i))

# remove quotes in list elements for easier export to numpy array
mean_list = ", ".join(mean_list)
print(mean_list)
```

Output:

```
'mean0, mean1, mean2, mean3, mean4, mean5'
```

Post-processing:

```
mean_array = np.array([mean0, mean1, mean2, mean3, mean4, mean5])
mean_array = mean_array.round(2)
mean_array
```

Output:

```
[ 2.67,  5.33, 13.  , 36.67, 43.33, 53.5 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can help.
In case you know the number of chunks. You can use Numpy to create an array of n chunks. Numpy evaluates the chunk size automatically.

```
import numpy as np
mydata = [2, 5, 1, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 33, 65, 34, 11, 42]
mydata = np.array(mydata) #convert list to Numpy array
number_chuncks = 6 #wanted number of chunks
chunks = np.array_split(mydata,number_chuncks)
print('chunks: ', chunks)
```

Result:

```
chunks:  [array([2, 5, 1]), array([5, 3]), array([8, 4]), array([ 2, 33]), array([65, 34]), array([11, 42])]
```

The expected number of Chunks can be calculated this way:

```
data_length = mydata.size
spacing = np.linspace(0, data_length, number_chuncks)
chunk_size = spacing[1]
print('Expected Chunk size: ',chunk_size)
```

Result:

```
Expected Chunk size:  2.6
```

That's why some chunks are size 3 and other of size 2 in chunks array.

Finally, the means can be calculated as:

```
list_of_means = [np.mean(c) for c in chunks]
print('Means: ',list_of_means)
```

Result:

```
Means:  [ 2.67  4.    6.   17.5  49.5  26.5 ]
```